Load Http response options to p-dropdown
I want to load options from the primeng component, from an http response that contains a list.
But no matter what options I try, the options come up empty, even though the data is loaded into the variable.
Source:
component:
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {
  perfiles$!: Observable<Perfil[]>;
  selectedPerfil?: Perfil;

  preguntas!: VistaPreviaEntrevistaDto[];
  selectedProduct!: any;

  constructor(private integradorService: IntegradorService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.cargarVistaPreviaEntrevista();
    // this.integradorService.listPerfiles().subscribe((data: Perfil[]) => {
    //   this.perfiles$ = Observable<data>;
    // })
    this.perfiles$ = this.integradorService.listPerfiles().pipe(
      map(perfil => perfil)
    );
    this.perfiles$.subscribe(
      (perfiles: Perfil[]) => {
        console.log('Perfiles:', perfiles);
      },
      (error) => {
        console.error('Error al obtener perfiles:', error);
      }
    );

    // this.cargarListaPerfiles();
    // this.perfiles = [
    //   {
    //     name: "Backend Java Enginier"
    //   },
    //   {
    //     name: "Frontend"
    //   },
    //   {
    //     name: "Data Science"
    //   },
    //   {
    //     name: "App Mobile Developer"
    //   }
    // ]
  }

  cargarVistaPreviaEntrevista(): void {
    this.integradorService.list().subscribe(
      data => {
        this.preguntas = data;
      },
      err => console.log(err)
    );
  }

  // cargarListaPerfiles(): void {
  //   this.integradorService.listPerfiles().subscribe(
  //     (data) => {
  //       this.perfiles = data;
  //     },
  //     err => console.log(err)
  //   )
  // }

}


html:
<p-dropdown *ngIf="perfiles$ | async as perfiles" [(ngModel)]="selectedPerfil" optionLabel="name" [showClear]="true"
      placeholder="Select a City" [options]="(perfiles$ | async)!"></p-dropdown>

service:
  public listPerfiles(): Observable<Perfil[]> {
    return this.httpClient.get<Perfil[]>(`${this.orquestadorURL}/v1/entrevistador/public/perfiles`);
  }

interface:
export interface Perfil {
  name: string
}

I am using Angular 17, I tried every way, as you can see in the comments.
Thanks for your answers

Can you share the response returned for your "perfiles" API as JSON snippet?

@DESTROYERGG issue to reproducible stackblitz
